# Canvas not working when inside a for loop

Tags: loops, canvas

**Goal:**
I'm trying to load 32 images, then use drawImage function & save the modified image to the same folder.

**Errors:** There are no error messages.

**What I tried:**

```js
                const chessLettersArr = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
                for (const letter of chessLettersArr) {
                    for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                        if (row[i][letter] !== '-') {
                                Canvas.loadImage(path.join(__dirname, `../images/chesspieces/${row[i][letter]}.png`)).then((image) => { 
                                    ctx.drawImage(image, utils.chessLetter(letter), utils.chessNo(row[i].number.toString()), 170, 170)
                                })
                        }
                    }
                }
```

This code does not draw any images at all **even though when I console log 'image'**, it'd say '[ complete]'

Dependency is 'Canvas' [npm i canvas]

Thanks for reading & please help me if you know this issue!

Comment: You got to simplify your troubleshooting ... start with just one image ... Does it work if you just do one image? if that works maybe the problem is on what you are not showing those `utils` functions are not giving back the correct locations

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I did in fact test with just 1 image & it worked well. The utils functions also worked; I console logged them & they show the correct numbers (Also used in the one image & it works), it just doesn't work inside a loop.

Comment: Show the code for those utils

Comment: You are not showing **when** you do "save the modified image to the same folder", but given your loop doesn't save any of the promises, it must be at the wrong time. You need to await all the images have loaded and been drawn to the canvas.

Comment: Yes Kaiido, I thought about that & already tried this
                                await Canvas.loadImage(path.join(__dirname, `../images/chesspieces/${row[i][letter]}.png`)).then((image) => { 
                                    ctx.drawImage(image, utils.chessLetter(letter), utils.chessNo(row[i].number.toString()), 170, 170)
                                })

Though it doesn't work still

Comment: Show your code, until your call to export the canvas